# How to authenticate when I try to git clone from azure git?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-git-deployment

I try to clone my app service from git local rep from azure platform to local env (on PC).
But when I do

```
git clone < https://adminusername@my.azure.url.torepo/appser.git>
```

console asks me about authentication with adminusername login. But what the password? It is not MicrosoftAppPassword, case when I try to use it, authentication  is failed.

What is the password?

Comment: What kind of account is `adminusername` ? is it your own account ?

Comment: "from git local rep"? Is the source repository local, or is it not?

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> How to authenticate when I try to git clone from azure git?

You could use your personal access token (PAT) or SSH to authenticate when you try to git clone from azure git.

[Authenticate with personal access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)

And the command like:

```
https://<OrganizationName>@dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/MyTestProject/_git/TestSample
```

Then we need to **replace** the **first** `OrganizationName` with **PAT**. So, it will be:

```
https://<PAT>@dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/MyTestProject/_git/TestSample
```

Or you can use the SSH key to authenticate:

[Use SSH key authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=current-page)

```
git clone git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/fabrikam-fiber/FabrikamFiber/FabrikamFiber
```

Last but not least, You could also install **Git Credential Managers** to login in Azure devops. After it installed, it will pop up a window to let your enter username and password when you use git clone command:

[Use Git Credential Managers to authenticate to Azure Repos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/set-up-credential-managers?view=azure-devops)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

One regular way to clone a repo from Azure Devops is to ask the admin to add your own account to the group of people that can clone the repo, and use your own account.

Another option, if using the `adminusername` account is mandatory, is to generate an ssh key on your machine, have the admin add your public key on the repo (linked to the `adminusername` account), and clone the repo through ssh.

Answer (score -1):

```
# Get system value
$ git config --system --get https.proxy
$ git config --system --get http.proxy

# Get global value
$ git config --global --get https.proxy
$ git config --global --get http.proxy

# Check configuration for your user
$ cat $HOME/.gitconfig

# Unset system value
$ git config --system --unset https.proxy
$ git config --system --unset http.proxy

# Unset global value
$ git config --global --unset https.proxy
$ git config --global --unset http.proxy


Your proxy could also be set as an environment variable. Check if your environment has any of the env variables http_proxy or https_proxy set up and unset them. Examples of how to set up:

# Linux
export http_proxy=http://proxy:8080
export https_proxy=https://proxy:8443 

# Windows
set http_proxy http://proxy:8080 
set https_proxy https://proxy:8443**strong text**
```